# Insert PHP form in PostgresSQL database

Tags: php, html, postgresql

So i'm building a website where you can buy tickets etc. So I want to have a login system, I started building the website and started with the PHP code to sign in but I always get the error Array?? It does work when I only want to insert a variable email and the rest plain text.

I've spend a whole week trying different methods etc. But I don't get why it doesn't work.

I even get the same error when I use constants instead of POST variables...

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
  userId SERIAL,
  email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  firstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  lastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  age INT NOT NULL,
  organizer BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  region VARCHAR(30),
  favouriteGenre VARCHAR(15),
  description VARCHAR(200),

  PRIMARY KEY(userId)
);
```

```
<?php

  require 'globals.php';

  try {
    $db_conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_password);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: ".$e->getMessage()."\n");
  }

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $pwdConfirm = $_POST['confirm'];
  $firsName = $_POST['firstName'];
  $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
  $age = $_POST['age'];
  $rol = $_POST['rol'];
  $region = $_POST['region'];
  $favGenre = $_POST['favGenre'];
  $description = $_POST['description'];

  //TODO inputChecks

  $query = $db_conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (email, password, firstName, lastName, age, organizer)
                              VALUES (:email, :password, :firstName, :lastName, :age, :organizer)');
  $query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
  $query->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
  $query->bindParam(':firstName', $firstName, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
  $query->bindParam(':lastName', $lastName, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
  $query->bindParam(':age', $age, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $query->bindParam(':organizer', $firstName, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);

  if ($query->execute()) {
    echo "success!";
  } else {
    die("Execute query error: ".$db_conn->errorInfo());
  }

  $db_conn = NULL;
```

I expect it to insert it into the database and don't give an error anymore.

Comment: Can you show us exact error message you get?

Comment: I literally get "Array" back from errorInfo(), is there a way to get more details?

Comment: I tried it on the web server and now I get a better error message: **Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/siebedreesen/public_html/project/PHP/signin.php on line 29
Execute query error: Array**

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$query = $db_conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (email, password, firstName, lastName, age, organizer,region, favouriteGenre, description)
                              VALUES (:email, :password, :firstName, :lastName, :age, :organizer, :region, :favouriteGenre, :description)');
  $query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
  $query->bindParam(':password', $pwd, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
  $query->bindParam(':firstName', $firstName, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
  $query->bindParam(':lastName', $lastName, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
  $query->bindParam(':age', $age, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $query->bindParam(':organizer', $firstName, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
  $query->bindParam(':region', $region, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':favouriteGenre', $favGenre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':description',  $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

One of the possible causes of the error you are getting is that you are trying to insert 6 values into a table with 9 fields.Another possible cause of the bug is that you have defined the variable for password as $pwd but use $password variable when binding parameters.

Comment: Please share the table structure/fields for the table users.@SiebeDreesen

Comment: Same error :( is there maybe a way that I can get more details about the error?